# Is there a way to pre-render frames in aframe?

Tags: aframe

So I am basically trying to modify an existing multi-user VR setup (users connected via network) that uses a-frame. I want to modify such that a Machine Learning model is used to predict frames within the next time-frame (for example: next 500 milliseconds), and these frames are pre-rendered (not displayed, just rendered before-hand so that it takes less time to display in the future). Since this is a multi-user setup with users connected via network, at the time when the actual frame needs to be rendered (i.e: users send their coordinates/orientation/other-info), I want to only selectively render the part of the frame that wasn't correctly pre-rendered by the ML model's prediction.

Personally, I don't see how this is directly possible, but if anyone has done something similar or has any ideas, please let me know.